# Newsstand Download Queue Management

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, newsstand-kit

Can u please let me knw what is the status of the `NKIssue` when it is added in the queue waiting for download to start??

Out of these 3 :

```
NKIssueContentStatusAvailable
NKIssueContentStatusDownloading
NKIssueContentStatusNone.
```

I'm getting `NKIssueContentStatusDownloading` Status even for the queued Issues.

Comment: I would say then that the status describes the intention, not the reality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple documentation says the following in the overview of the NewsstandKit object [NKLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NKLibrary_Class/NKLibrary/NKLibrary.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NKLibrary):

> The downloadingAssets array holds any downloading assets for any issues. (A downloading asset is represented by a NKAssetDownload object.) A newsstand content application should, when it launches, iterate through this array and call downloadWithDelegate: on each item to have the downloaded assets completely processed.

I am using deductive reasoning to assume that once a NKIssue has had it's downloadWithDelegate: method called it keeps the status NKIssueContentStatusDownloading until it has been removed from the NKLibrary or downloaded.

Also, if a download has been interrupted and needs to be resumed, you would loop through all the NKIssues in NKLibrary's downloadingAssets property to re-call it's downloadWithDelegate to resume it.  However, who knows when the downloadingAssets is *cleared* or *reset*.  I don't even know where we would find that out.

That's the best answer I could find.

Comment: Glad to help. I've been stuck too. Haha.